# Eclipse is not able to run nor open a webdriver. TestNG No tests found. Nothing was run

Tags: java, eclipse

Public class loadChrome
{

```
@Test
Public void openBrowser()
{
   //Setting up the driver path on the piece of code below
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path goes here");

   //In this line, I am defining the web driver instance 
   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
   driver.get("https://www.google.com/");//Telling the driver to open Google website
   driver.close(); //Closing the driver
}
```

}

I have tried debugging the code to see where it is failing. I noticed it cannot even simply open the web driver instance.

I expect the output to be:Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0, but the actual output is Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0

Comment: what is your import for Test?

Comment: Hi, my imports are as follows:
package loadBrowser;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;